# Check is Youtube video is a live stream

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to check given youtube link is currently streaming live? I need to catch moment, when it is ended and link become an ordinary video.

Answer (score 2):

You could [check the duration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information) periodically. During live events, `getDuration` returns the elapsed time since the video started streaming. So you can assume that a video is live until this value stops changing.